# Restrict a div to get only particular stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project which is completely done by HTML5,MVC 4,CSS 3, JQuery, LINQ. There are a lot of ui,li and other html controls and we have done styles for those elements.

Now i have a situation that i must include a JQ Grid (http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) , we were using our own client side grid. Now what the problem is if i use the style sheet of the JQ Grid on the page, there is a possibility to get affected to other element also. Anyway i am gonna use that particular grid inside a div element i need that style sheet should be affected to that the elements which all are inside that div.

Is there any possibilities?

(I wonder if this is possible in this way ;)

```
 <div id="jqgridcontainer" stylesheet="styles/jqgrid/jqstyles.css">  my ui elements here </div>
```

I know its not possible in this way )

NB: editing http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-custom.css[^] by adding "jqgridcontainer" div id to all the element css is not possible.

Comment: It's not possible in the terms you are thinking. You would need to change all the styles in the stylesheet to only apply to that div.

Comment: You can checkout from here .[DIVs inside another DIV inside another DIV with CSS][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438437/divs-inside-another-div-inside-another-div-with-css

Comment: @paulie Yeah i know its not possible in that way, but i need an alternative for that

Comment: Do you have its less or sass code? If so then it would be easy to modify it according to your own needs.

Comment: @Emmad I explained my need already in that mark up, i know its not possible in that way, but i am looking for an alternative way

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263616/link-external-css-file-only-for-specific-div/26264176#26264176 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667874/limit-scope-of-external-css-to-only-a-specific-element.

Comment: @torazaburo but i could not find your answer in answer section. You commented in my question, How can i up vote a comment?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't add css file to one div, you can only add style to the all document.
The only way i see to use css file to only one part of your page is to put your grid in an iframe (which is not really good...)

Comment: Yeah that i know, But i need an alternative for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `<div id="jqgridcontainer" stylesheet="styles/jqgrid/jqstyles.css">`. If jqstyles.css is not a big file you can change the `div{...}` rules in it with `div.jq {...}` and add class jq to your divs that you want to use jq styles. If jqstyles.css is so big that you can't go through it all, give your divs, which you want to have your style, a class like '`myDivClass`' and change your css to div.myDivClass {...}. You may need to mark your rules as `!important` or just reference jqstyles.css first and your css 2nd..

Comment: Sorry buddy that's not what i am looking for. I know the mark up which i used is not applicable. I wrote like that to make my question more understandable.

Comment: Fair enough. Have you considered my suggestions? What are the issues with implementing them?

Comment: But if i do as you said, there will be problem with the other UI elements, there will be a css crash, i dont want this css style to be applied for the elements which all are outside of my div. And please see my updated question

Comment: @sibeesh I saw you can't edit jqstyles.css. Another option is to use `#myCss a{color:red}` in your own css and then mark the sections of the html to use your css inside a `<div class="myCss">`. But that probably won't fix it for you either.

Answer (score 0):

Use ids and classes properly to avoid all the division to get the same property..